# Conditional rewrite rules - How to apply only one of these two sets of rules

Tags: mod-rewrite

If there is `browse_by_exam` or `my_study_centre` in the 1st position starting from `project_name` as in

```
http://project_name/browse_by_exam/type/classes/...
http://project_name/my_study_centre/page_sort/1,20,name,asc/...
```

Then apply these 2 rules:-

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1 
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-\_]+)/([a-z0-9\-\_]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2
```

For all other URLs apply these rules:-

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Thanks,

Sandeepan

Comment: @skaffman I think I applied meaningful tags, why did you remove those?

Comment: Because it's a question about mod-rewrite, and that's the tag that people will be looking for. Tags are there to categorize, not describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself. The following worked:-

```
############Following rules apply only to browse_by_exam and my_study_centre

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 ^(browse_by_exam|my_study_centre) 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
#################################################


###Following rules apply to all other pages (other than browse_by_exam and my_study_centre)
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1 

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-\_]+)/([a-z0-9\-\_]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-\_]+)/([a-z0-9\-\_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_+]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-\_]+)/([a-z0-9\-\_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_+]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4
```

Cheers,

Sandeepan

Answer (score 0):

None of these URLs are matched by the patterns of your two rules. But if you want to write rules that match your conditions, try a rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(browse_by_exam|my_study_centre)($|/) foobar [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I am not getting it clearly... if you could show with my example..